# I've got some weird characters in ckeditor dialogs

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, character

Has anyone else had problems with ckeditor and characters like this?
I've just downloaded a new version and I'm a little lost.

[image: weird characaters]

Thanks for your help.
Richard

Comment: have you take a look at your response readers to see the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your code for charset utf-8 ? 
If not or if you are not sure then this could be the problem with the character encoding.

Try add this before sending any html:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

And this one to the html `<head></head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Yeah, you would think that it's encoding or something but it's ckeditor I can see the line here
label:C.protocol,'default':'http://',items:[['http://â€Ž','http://'],['https://â€Ž','https://'],['ftp://â€Ž','ftp://'],
But in the script I see 
label:C.protocol,'default':'http://',items:[['http://‎','http://'],['https://‎','https://'],['ftp://‎','ftp://'],['news://‎','news://'],[D.other,'']]

So why is it ok in one area but not another - just confusing!

Comment: Well, go figure I went into notepad++ removed the areas where the chars were and put them back in by hand it did it!
I don't know how but it did